# Can I make a two column Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2010

I have a report that has one detail row for every day of the month. I would like to present the info with days 1 to 15 in one 'group column' on the left, and the other days on the right. Each of these 'group columns' would contain four information columns.

I can do this manually by splitting the report DB query columns, but I'm really hoping there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the details section in the section expert check the check box "Format With Multiple Columns" (and in the Common tab ). Additional tab "Layout" will be added. You can set there the number of columns and the direction (you need to choose "down then across")

Comment: Thanks. It looks like this is indeed the solution, but it doesn't work on my machine. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I'd like to add that I had to also select "Format Groups with multiple column" on the Layout tab.  And reduce the width of the details fields to fit the column widths.  I am using Crystal Reports 2011.