# Crystal Report Groups Duplicate My Values

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm trying create two groups from two different tables. I choose create new crystal report (As A blank report) then i create two groups like following images:

[image: Create Group]

[image: CreateGroup]

Then I'm choosing the table. I'm doing this once again with another table i want.
My Crystal report design look like this:
[image: Design]

Now my Result is this:
[image]

But I want to take this result:(This result is painted)

[image]

Maybe it looks like easy for you, but i need a helping hand for solving this.

I choosed  link options(Full inner join)
[image]

In Design Form
[image]

Comment: have you linked the tables? if not link tables then don't create group 2 instead create group 1 and place table 2 in details thats sufficient

Comment: Thank you  Sir i link my categories and it works now But it doesnt show them in same Row. Look my picture i just updated.

Comment: can you show me the design? Its diffuclt to check in preview

Comment: Of course, i updated. Maybe Should i do something with sections?

Comment: Place group1 name in group header 2

Comment: I get first result again.:( I think something is going on with link options

Comment: Can you post what is tpur data in table 1 and table2 and also what is the common filed in both tables

Comment: What you mean common field? I Just linked example field (incomes.category) with (outgoings.category)

Comment: If your join is incorrect then diplication will happen and result will be strange

Answer (score 0):

The grouping functionality within Crystal maintains the data relationship and makes it easier to read by not repeating the group text for each line item - if you group by "A", you will see all items, including the "group 2 duplicates" so long as they are in group A. Adding a second group will further refine the subset of results.

This is the intended and expected behavior for Crystal - SQL-level grouping is different and is used for aggregate functions, among other things.

If you are trying to create a multi-column report, look at this 
[Can I make a two column Crystal Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906896/can-i-make-a-two-column-crystal-report) - Under Section Expert, go to Details and click the box "format with Multiple Columns", then click Layout at the top and enter the detail size, in inches, as well as the gap between details. if you want your groups to continue in the additional columns, click the "Format groups with Multiple Column" checkbox.

If this does not satisfy your requirement, you may have to reevaluate the report requirements and the dataset limitations.