# Dynamic columns number in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to make a report that runs a query on database, it gets the count of items used in a specific transaction grouped by their name, so both item's name and its count are retrieved from db, is it possible ?

[image]

The query will get results similar to this:

[image]

Comment: You can make a multi-column report. But the number of columns isn't dynamic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17906896/can-i-make-a-two-column-crystal-report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cross tabs for this purpose.

Create a cross tab and use Item name in columns and count in rows.

There are many links when google, below is as sample

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/cross_tab_layout.htm

Comment: more details please or some links?.. I didn't use it before, also I'm new to CR.